# Bridging a router

Tags: bridge-router, bridging

I work from home and my company is insisting that I bridge my comcast dual band router to improve performance.  Comcast tells me I will lose my wifi if I do this. I understand that the bridged network now becomes my only network but how does it impact my wireless devices including a smart tv? And what about guests that use my network when visiting?

Comment: Your question is unclear. What are you bridging the router with? In general, yes - if you are bridging a modem or equivalent then that device wont appear in your network or provide WIFI. That said, you would typically bridge with another router and that router may be able to provide WIFI.

Comment: I very much doubt this will improve performance in any way. Sure hope your employer will also buy you the new router this endeavor will require!

Answer (score 1):

> Comcast tells me I will lose my WiFi if I do this.

You will lose the WiFi capabilities of the modem (which is really a modem/router combination).

> I understand that the bridged network now becomes my only network but how does it impact my wireless devices including a smart TV? And what about guests that use my network when visiting?

Essentially, if you are bridging your cable modem, the cable modem will act only as a modem. You will undoubtedly want to purchase a separate router and attach it to the bridged modem to provide wireless connections or to easily attach multiple computers.